# Where to use CGPathRelease?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am creating a line for my SKShapeNode using a CGMutablePathRef. Reading up on the usage a bit, I came across a post saying that it's important to use CGPathRelease when you're done using the path. Now I am wondering, when can I release the path? Will releasing it while the SKShapeNode still exists do any harm?

Oh and, sorry if CGPathRelease isn't used anymore since the introduction of garbage collection, I couldn't find out if it still had to be used or not, so please correct me if it's not needed anymore.

Comment: Garbage collection is dead. Fuggedaboutit. Nowadays we use ARC or manual reference counting. It doesn't matter which for CGPathRefs, since those are Core Foundation objects, and ARC doesn't memory-manage CF objects. I'm a little fuzzy on how you figure out when system frameworks take ownership of CF objects myself....

Comment: I figure you have to assume rational behavior on their part, @DuncanC; the node shouldn't expect you to manage the memory for its path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The node will take ownership of the `CGPathRef` when you set its `path` property. You can and *should* use `CGPathRelease()` anytime after you're done manipulating the path and have passed it to the node.

Comment: Is there an easy explanation as to why that is necessary?

Comment: There's an explanation, but I'm not sure what you mean, @Vingdoloras. Why _what_ is necessary?

Comment: Explicitly calling a method to release the CGPathRef. I'm new to Objective C and everything Apple, last thing I heard about memory management was that garbage collection got introduced in... iOS 5? Now I get told that garbage collection is dead... I guess I have some more research to do...

Comment: It's not garbage collection, @Vingdoloras, it's just the compiler automating the reference counting that used to be done manually. But it only operates on Objective-C objects. `CGPathRef` is not such an object -- it's a pure-C-based pseudo-object, and as such, you still need to manage it explicitly. The [Memory Management Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html) is the relevant doc.